# iOS - UITableView Index: Is there a way to highlight the selected alphabet?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitableview

I've a table view for which I've provided/turned on the Alphabetical Index on the right side. This does help in jumping through the content.

Now I was wondering whether there is a way to highlight the letter/alphabet (or make letter bold) which is selected? 
e.g. If User taps 'B' to scroll to rows starting with 'B' letter text, then Index should highlight the letter 'B'.

I can understand this can be achieved using custom index bar view. However, I'm more intent on finding whether there is native support to do this.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: is it that hard to achieve this? I was only looking for a clean way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After my digging to the documentation and internet. I think there is no easy way to highlight the current selected character in the section indices. We could only change the text color, background color and highlighted background color.

I suggest you to do it yourself or open an issue in this library [GDIIndexBar](https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar). Then others could help you do this, for you and for all.